# ViewModel Problems

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I am struggling to get my ViewModel working for viewing details. I have it working for creating a new record but just can't figure out what to do to simply view the data already registered.

I have two models

User (contains regular stuff like UserName , Password, email etc) and then -

```
public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
public virtual UserDetails UserDetails { get; set; }
```

There is a 1:1 relationship with UserDetails which just contails a few additional items like FirstName, LastName and then

```
    [Required]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
```

I then have a ViewModel called RegisterViewModel that contains the necessary registration details from both User and UserDetails.

In my AccountController Register method I have

```
MembershipCreateStatus createStatus = MembershipService.CreateUser(viewModel.UserName, viewModel.Password, viewModel.Email);

                if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
                {
                    TRSContext context = new TRSContext();
                    //FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);

                    User newuser = context.Users
                        .Include(i => i.UserDetails)
                        .Where(i => i.UserName == viewModel.UserName)
                        .Single();
                    newuser.UserDetails = new UserDetails();

                    Role adminRole = context.Roles.Find("User");
                    newuser.Roles = new List<Role>();
                    newuser.Roles.Add(adminRole);

                    newuser.UserDetails.Firstname = viewModel.FirstName;
                    newuser.UserDetails.Lastname = viewModel.LastName;
                    newuser.UserDetails.Address1 = viewModel.Address1;
                    newuser.UserDetails.Address2 = viewModel.Address2;
                    newuser.UserDetails.City = viewModel.City;
                    newuser.UserDetails.Postcode = viewModel.Postcode;
                    newuser.UserDetails.Country = viewModel.Country;

                    context.SaveChanges();
```

This all works fine and I can register a new user with data being stored in both User and UserDetails tables.

My problem is retrieving the data again to display on the Users/Index page. This should display details from both Users and UserDetails for each user registered. I have tried numerous different things to get it working but keep getting errors. I have gone through books and the sample apps on the asp.net mvc site but can't find any examples for something like this with a 1:1 relationship. I thought that after getting the register part working then this would be the easy part but I can't see how to do this.

In my user controller for Index do I need to pass in a viewModel? Or do I just set up the viewModel within the Index method and then pass to the view? I tried setting up the view model in here without success, thinking it would be similar to the set up in the accounts controller but I get errors no matter what I try.

Edit - I have tried adding a new ViewModel called UserDetaisData that simply contains -

```
namespace TRS.ViewModels
{
    public class UserDetailsData
    {
        public IEnumerable<User> User { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<UserDetails> UserDetails { get; set; }

    }
}
```

But I don't know if this is the correct thing to do.

Then in the Index method of the User controller I have -

```
public ViewResult Index()
        {
            var viewModel = new UserDetailsData();
```

As I think I need to instantiate a new viewModel that I can send back to the view.

I then have the option to do viewModel.User =  and  viewModel.UserDetails = .Is this what I should be doing? Can I retrieve the data from these two models and then send all back to the view in the new viewModel?

Can anyone give advice or point me to an example with a similar case?

Thanks

Comment: It's not helpful to say "I get errors" and then don't tell us what the errors are.  It's also not helpful to vaguely describe what you've done, rather than supplying code you've used that didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I can update with some of the things I've tried but I think I was off in the wrong direction so was hoping to try something first that might work. Just struggling to find any example to try.

Comment: I think you're on the right track, more or less.  I don't see where you are fetching any data from the database, though.  Don't forget to do that to populate the view model before sending it off to the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new view model to show all the data you want to show and then pass that to a view (combining relevant fields from both your Users and UserDetails entities).  Alternatively, you can pass an HTML partial with a parameter of the ID of the User to display UserDetails.

Comment: Should I not be using the RegisterViewModel I already have, this contains the data from the two models I want to show. Is it better to create a new one for this purpose?

Comment: If I create a new ViewModel for use on the Index page do I need to just add public IEnumerable<User> User{ get; set; }
public IEnumerable<UserDetails> UserDetails{ get; set; } ?

Comment: You only need to create a new view model if the validation requirements are different between the two views, or if the data requirements are different between them.

Comment: If you can get away with using your current Model then just do that.  Otherwise, create a new one.  You should just be able to loop through the single view model and loop through other variables in your view using `foreach`.